# How can I combine multiple screenshots in Skitch?

Tags: macos, screen-capture, image-editing, skitch

With Skitch, I often find myself wanting to take screenshots of different parts of the screen, annotating them, and combining them into one image. I could use a separate program for this last step, such as Acorn, but is it possible to do this from within Skitch?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nope, not possible within Skitch.

The quickest workaround I've found to achieve that is using Keynote as a canvas, so you can combine the image in no time :

- open a new 'White' theme in Keynote
- drag & drop the 2 images from Skitch to Keynote
- align the images in Keynote, resize, do some edits if necessary
- take a snapshot with Skitch

Answer (score 3):

Can't do it with Skitch, as noted. But LittleSnapper will work. It creates an image for each screen, then you can drop them all into a photo imaging app and compose into one image.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny, Skitch has some weird limitations, so I use Powerpoint for this. Insert two screenshots, side by side, group them together then ctrl-click to "Save as Picture"